# CDT Juno Ubuntu "g++ not in PATH"

Tags: c++, eclipse, eclipse-cdt

Of course g++ is installed and in PATH, but no matter what I do eclipse Juno on Ubuntu does not find it. Has anyone being able to solve that?

which g++ gives /usr/bin/g++

g++ is installed on my Ubuntu

Comment: Do you see g++ run when you type `g++` at the command line?

Comment: @DrewDormann Of course

Comment: if you right click in your project go to properties>>c/c++ build and click on settings what does appear after "Command" ?

Comment: C/C+ build >> Settings does not have command on Juno. I see Configuration: Debug, Binary Parsers and Error Parsers.